# React failed to compile due to syntax error

Tags: reactjs

```
./src/App.js
SyntaxError: C:\Users\user\Desktop\coding 101\Portfolio\src\App.js: Unexpected token (38:53)

  36 |             navbarScroll>
  37 |
> 38 |             <Nav.Link to ="/Home>HOME</Nav.Link> |{" "}
     |                                                      ^
  39 |             // <Nav.Link to ="/About">ABOUT</Nav.Link> 
  40 |             <Nav.Link to ="/Project">PROJECT</Nav.`enter code here`Link>
  41 |             <Nav.Link to ="/Contact">CONTACT</Nav.Link>
```

Please guys help me out, what I'm I doing wrong here

Answer (score 0):

There is no closing quotation on line 38 in the to attribute after /Home.